# NSPathControl and Auto Layout

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspathcontrol

I'm having some issues with `NSPathControl` and Auto Layout.

I want the path control to resize with the window. Which means, if I expand the width of the window, the `NSPathControl` should expand too. This works.

Now the problem is, that if I change the URL of the path control to a longer URL, the path control expands automatically. I don't want that. I want the path control width to stay the same, except when the user resizes the window.

I tried pinning the width it, but then I can't resize the window at all...

Also, when I don't pin the window of the path control, I can't make it smaller than the actual content of the sub controls, which represent the URL.

Hope that makes sense.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Sorry, I guess I asked to fast.
I got it working like this:

---

### NSPathControl subclass

```
- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return NSMakeSize(NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric, NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for subclassing. You can tell your view how much to resist compression. By default the priority is set to `NSLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh`.  You are probably looking for `NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCannotResizeWindow`.  You can set this in your XIB in the **Size Inspector** for the control or take a look at NSView's [`setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forOrientation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setContentCompressionResistancePriority%3aforOrientation%3a).